# HDFS Audit Logs cmd operation meaning

Tags: hadoop

Would like to know details of HDFS Audit log "cmd" operation explanation.

cmd =(open|create|delete|rename|mkdirs|listStatus|setReplication|setOwner|setPermission)

Example: What does cmd=open meaning?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it means opening a file for read access

Answer (score -1):

- `open`   open a file for reading
- `create` create files
- `delete`  delete files
- `rename`  rename a file
- `mkdirs` make directories
- `listStatus` list files or directories status
- `setReplication`  set files replications
- `setOwner`    set file or dir owner
- `setPermission` set file of dir permission
- `getfileinfo` get files information